# TypeError referencing class method

Tags: python, class, methods, python-2.7, typeerror

Working with classes in one of my projects for the first time, I seem to be making a mistake somewhere that I can't pick.

```
class aiRespond:
    def generateResponse( self, external_input ):
        return external_input

    def giveResponse( self, external_input ):
        self.generateResponse(self, external_input)

aiResponder = aiRespond()
retrieve_ai_response = aiResponder.giveResponse()

while 1:
    external_input = raw_input("> ")
    print retrieve_ai_response(external_input)
```

Error:

```
TypeError: unbound method giveResponse() must be called with aiRespond instance as first argument (got str instance instead)
```

I have tried many different ways of structuring this. I would prefer `retrieve_ai_response = aiRespond.giveResponse` to be in one line as I am going to have a lot of things similar to this.

Would someone mind pointing out where I'm going on and why?

Comment: I also strongly advise that you use new-style classes (search for a definition of the differences and how you can use them). PEP 8, the Python style guide, is also something you might like to read (standard Python code will use its naming conventions, which would have names like `AIRespond`, `generate_response` and `ai_responder`).

Comment: @ChrisMorgan Thank you for the suggestion. I was particularly interested in PEP 8, as I have seen others suggest this to other posters as well. New-Style classes seem to be a tad confusing, but I'm going through some video tutorials of them as I speak. Thank you !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class aiRespond:
    def generateResponse( self, external_input ):
        return external_input

    def giveResponse( self, external_input ):
        return self.generateResponse( external_input) #remove self as parameter,add return

aiResponder = aiRespond()
retrieve_ai_response = aiResponder.giveResponse #remove "()"

while 1:
    external_input = raw_input("> ")
    print retrieve_ai_response(external_input)
```

I have modified you code,Hope it works!

Comment: Thank you, this worked exactly as needed. I see that I was doubling up on my parameters.

Answer (score 3):

You're assigning the result of the function giveResponse to retrieve_ai_response.

Try:

```
retrieve_ai_response = aiResponder.giveResponse
```

Also get rid of 'self' as the first argument in the giveResponse function body. As you're calling self.generateResponse you don't need it:

```
def giveResponse( self, external_input ):
    return self.generateResponse(external_input)
```

Comment: `giveResponse` should return a value.

Comment: Thanks chm I have modified the response.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. I'm not sure whom to give the 'tick' to as you both answered so exclusively and well. Thank you! :)